# SQL SELECT whitespace insensitive

Tags: php, sql, select, syntax

what is the bes way to get a MySQL SELECT result no matter if user enter string with spaces or not? For example in database i have column value "B 009" and i want to select it for parameters "b 009" and "b009". 
I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) and [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE REPLACE(column_name, ' ', '') LIKE REPLACE('b 009', ' ', '');
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17e2d9/1/0

The value `b 009` is your input value. The string comparison using `LIKE` is not case-sensitive unless one of the operands is case-sensitive (uses a case-sensitive collation or is a binary string).

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to be case insensitive, use upper

```
SELECT * FROM table_name  
WHERE upper(REPLACE(column_name, ' ', '')) 
LIKE upper(REPLACE(value_to_be_matched, ' ', ''));
```

For [MYSQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d14fd/2),

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE 
REPLACE(column1, ' ' , '') = REPLACE('b 009', ' ', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT is case insensitive. For whitespace, assume your column is "name" in table "user", you can do this using a regexp:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE name REGEXP 'B *009'
```

Comment: This is only specific solution to a particular value but how will this be generalized

Comment: True, but what if "B0 09" should not be matched? I guess we'll leave it to the person who asked the question to use what suits his/her requirement.